# Can I delete data from my local pouchDB without the delete replicating to couchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Is there a way I can clear down the data in my local pouchDB without the changes being replicated to the online couchDB.

I am currently using the db.sync function with live: true

The context for this is I have lots of users entering orders in an offline first environment and would like to cleardown the data every few days to keep the application quick but new lose the orders from couchDB

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, there is a long running open issue for `purge` @ https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/802 which would do what you want, but it has not been implemented yet.

What is your use case, are you doing a 2 way sync and seeing remote updates locally or are you only doing push replication to send the orders? One way to work around this is to periodically create a fresh database locally that only contains the orders you care about.

Comment: I am doing a 2 way sync as orders will come into the couchDB via an online site and need to be visible to the local pouchDB instantly. Orders can be entered from the local application which is an AngularJS app wrapped in Electron and reads / writes to the local db in the database. As orders come in from the web they are also made available to the Electron app too. If I destroy the local will it not just sync all the records back into itself when re-created?